# OS X equivalents for Ubuntu's genisoimage and qemu-img

Tags: disk-image

How do I achieve the same result on OS X 10.9 as I do on Ubuntu with commands:

```
$ genisoimage -output init.iso -volid cidata -joliet -rock user-data meta-data
```

and

```
$ qemu-img convert -O raw disk.img disk.img.raw
```

Answer (score 11):

I had to this exact same thing for generating a local cloud init setup.

`mkisofs` is a drop in replacement for `genisoimage` from what I can tell.

```
mkisofs -output init.iso -volid cidata -joliet -rock {user-data,meta-data}
```

You can `brew install cdrtools` which includes `mkisofs`.

Comment: Except it is missing the -e flag for EFI

Comment: 5 years later, thank you for this!!

Answer (score 10):

```
$ hdiutil makehybrid -o init.iso -hfs -joliet -iso -default-volume-name cidata config/
```

Where config/ contains meta-data and user-data.

To install qemu, simply run the following from the command-line:

```
$ brew install qemu
```

Comment: Just wanted to say that I recently tried this method and it works perfectly. Thank you!